# How to build Linq query dynamically based on certain conditions

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I have a data entry form where user will input DateFrom and DateTo fields.

```
Select From Date: <input type="text" id="datepickerfrom" name="datepickerfrom"/>
Select To Date: <input type="text" id="datepickerto" name="datepickerto"/>
<asp:Button ID="btnGetData" runat="server" OnClick="BtnGetData_Click" Text="Get Error List" />
```

I want to build a Linq query that retrieves only top 100 records in case if no input provided.

If user provides DateFrom and does not provide DateTo, the user will select data which is greater than DateFrom up to DateTime.Now.

If user provides DateTo and does not provide DateFrom, the user will select data which is less then DateTo.

I have the following now:

```
public static List<ErrorLogData> GetLogErrorData(string appName, InputData data)
{
    SqlConnection con;
    List<ErrorLogData> errorLogData = null;
    string query = "";
    if (data.DateFrom == "" && data.DateTo == "")
    {
        query += "from ld in logData.errorLogs.Take(10000)";
    }

    if (data.DateFrom == "" && data.DateTo != "")
    {
        query += "from ld in logData.errorLogs where ld.errorTime <= " + data.DateTo;
    }

    if (data.DateFrom != "" && data.DateTo == "")
    {
        query += "from ld in logData.errorLogs where ld.errorTime >= " + data.DateFrom + " && <= " + DateTime.Now;
    }

    if (data.DateFrom != "" && data.DateTo != "")
    {
        query += "from ld in logData.errorLogs where ld.errorTime >= " + data.DateFrom + " && <= " + data.DateTo;
    }

    DateTime dateFrom = Convert.ToDateTime(data.DateFrom);
    DateTime dateTo = Convert.ToDateTime(data.DateTo);


    using (con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[conKey]))
    using (WebEntities logData = new WebEntities())
    {
        logData.CommandTimeout = 300;
        var errorLog = query + 
                       select new ErrorLogData
                       {
                           ErrorID = ld.errorID,
                           ErrorTime = ld.errorTime,
                           UserName = ld.username,
                           ErrorType = ld.errorType,
                           Error = ld.error,
                           ControlNumber = ld.controlNumber
                       };
        errorLogData = errorLog.ToList();
    }
    return errorLogData;
}
```

I'm not sure how to append `query` to "`select new ErrorLogData...`" statement to have the entire query.

What is the approach here?

Comment: I think you missed Sql Injection 101

Comment: Is it an option to use entity framework?

Comment: Not, necessarily. I can use regular way. I'm doing it for my own sake to learn Linq to Entity. Trying to see if there is a way to accomplish what I want using entity framework

Comment: So, is your WebEntities type a Linq To SQL class that inherits from System.Data.Linq.DataContext?

Comment: If not Entity Framework, Dapper will do exactly what you want here

Comment: I think my question was not that bad to be downgraded 3 times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just be able to use the IQueryable result of error log, and then perform lambda expressions for your if statements.

```
            List<ErrorLogData> errorLogData = null;
        DateTime dateFrom = Convert.ToDateTime(data.DateFrom);
        DateTime dateTo = Convert.ToDateTime(data.DateTo);


        //IQueryable errorLog
        var errorLog = from ld in logData.errorLogs
                       select new ErrorLogData
                       {
                           ErrorID = ld.errorID,
                           ErrorTime = ld.errorTime,
                           UserName = ld.username,
                           ErrorType = ld.errorType,
                           Error = ld.error,
                           ControlNumber = ld.controlNumber
                       };



        if (data.DateFrom == "" && data.DateTo == "")
        {
            errorLogData = errorLog.Take(10000);
        }

        if (data.DateFrom == "" && data.DateTo != "")
        {
            errorLogData = errorLog.where(x => x.ErrorTime <= dateTo).ToList();
            //query += "from ld in logData.errorLogs where ld.errorTime <= " + data.DateTo;
        }

        //contine to implement If


        return errorLogData;
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you are using some kind of LINQ data access technology, use something like the following:

```
private List<Entity> GetData(DateTime? dateFrom, DateTime? dateTo)
{
    IQueryable<Entity> query = ...; //Here reference your table

    if (dateFrom == null && dateTo == null)
    {
        query = query.Take(100);
    }
    else
    {
        DateTime dateToValue = dateTo ?? DateTime.Now;

        query = query.Where(x => x.Date <= dateToValue);

        if (dateFrom != null)
        {
            query = query.Where(x => x.Date >= dateFrom.Value);
        }
    }

    return query.ToList(); //This will actually execute the query. Here you can expand your query to select specific columns before executing ToList
}
```